# Fixed text move up when footer appears using wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, fixed, sticky

i'm using a wordpress template called "Lay Theme" and i want the information-text to be fixed on the left of my site. I fixed it using position:fixed, but when i scroll down and the text is slightly longer than other, it overlays the footer.
I want the text to move up when te footer appears, how do i fix this?

I gave the text-div the class "uitleg" (dutch for information)

Here is the example: https://www.zwtsr.nl/housenation-x-ade/

`.uitleg position: fixed; top: 45%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "position: sticky;"

```css
.container {
    width: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.content {
    height: 2000px;
}
.content .text {
    width: 50%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 50%;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px;
    background: #212121;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your answer!
How do i add this in the code of my site?
When i put it in the custom css, nothing happens..

Comment: @Jesse try to: .uitleg position: sticky; top: 45%; }
If you have two main divs, one in which you put text and the other in which you put e.g. photos (both are 50% wide), put a div with ".uitleg" class inside the main div for text.
e.g. 
<div class="text"><p class="uitleg"></p></div>
<div class="images"><img src="/" /></div>